# Cómo actualizar registros de firebase en Ionic3 al cargar un ngSwitch

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript, ionic2, ionic-framework

Estimados amigos de la comunidad, necesito si alguien puede orientarme en un tema sobre firebase, trabajo con Angular2 y angularfire. El tema es que tengo una pequeña función que me carga el contenido de una lista de una subrama, después de algunos quebraderos de cabeza lo logró hacer pero mi problema es que el resultado no me aparece al cargar la página sino que después de recargar al visitar otro ngSwitch de la página, al visitar por primera vez el ngSwitch en cuestión me aparece el árbol de indices y no el valor del nombre que aparece una vez recargo nuevamente.

El Código en cuestión

```js
//Código del archivo TS del html que carga la lista
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.firebaseService.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user){
        this.researchTypesLists = this.firebaseService.getResearchTypes();
        this.sourceTypeLists = this.firebaseService.getResearchSourceTypes();
      }else{
        this.researchTypesLists = null;
        this.sourceTypeLists = null;
      }
    });
  }
  
//Código del provider que carga la lista

getResearchSourceTypes(){
    return this.afd.list('/ResearchSourcesTypes', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'name',
      }
    }).map(list => {
      list.map(rstList => {
        rstList.researchType = rstList.researchType.map(oneRst => {
          firebase.database().ref('/ResearchTypes/'+oneRst+'/').on('value', snapshot => {
             oneRst = snapshot.val().name;
             //console.log(oneRst);
          });
          return oneRst;
        });
        return rstList;
      });
      return list;
    });
     
  }
```

```html
<div *ngSwitchCase="'sources'">
      <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-list *ngFor="let source of sourceTypeLists | async" padding-top>
                <ion-list-header color="light">
                  <button ion-button item-left clear color="danger" icon-only (click)="removeResearchSourceType(source.$key)" *ngIf="editMode">
                    <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
                  </button> 
                  {{ source.name }}
                </ion-list-header>
                <ion-item>
                  <b ion-text color="favorite">Type: </b><b>{{ source.type }}</b>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item text-wrap>
                  <b ion-text color="favorite">Research Type: </b>
                  <div *ngFor="let item of source.researchType">
                      <ion-badge>{{ item }}</ion-badge>
                  </div>
                </ion-item>
              </ion-list>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <ion-fab right bottom padding>
                <button ion-fab (click)="addResearchSourceType()" color="secondary">
                  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
                </button>
              </ion-fab>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
```

**Al cargar el ngSwitch aparece:**
[image: Al cargar ngSwitch por primera vez]
**Después de visitar en ngSwitch de Research Types y volver a Sources aparece como debería cargar:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agradece la ayuda ;)